# SQL Concat every other Row to return a string ["FistName LastName", "FisrtName LastName"] ,

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

This is beyond my knowledge any help would great!

I have a SQL Server table named `RegisteredUsers` that contains `FirstName` and `LastName`. I need to build a string ["FirstName LastName", "FirstName LastName"] for every 2 rows. I can build the string but I need to get

The first row to contain the results of 1st and 2nd rows FirstName LastName FirstName LastName
The second row to contain 3rd and 4th FirstName LastName FirstName LastName
and so on.

I am attempting to randomize and pair users up

I hoping to get something link this

```
Team1 | Team2
1 FN LN  | FN LN
2 FN LN  | FN LN
3 FN LN  | FN LN
4 FN LN  | FN LN
```

Thank for the help

Comment: How do you want to define the pairs?  Just arbitrarily or is there some field that orders them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `LEAD()` function in conjunction with `ROW_NUMBER()` in SQL Server 2012, or in SQL 2008 Server you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and a self-join.

SQL Server 2012:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT FN + ' ' + LN AS Team1
                    , LEAD(FN + ' ' + LN,1) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Team2
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT Team1, Team2
FROM cte
WHERE RN%2 > 0
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2f40/7/0)

SQL Server 2008:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT FN + ' ' + LN AS Team
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT a.Team AS Team1
      ,b.Team AS Team2
FROM cte a
JOIN cte b
  ON a.RN = b.RN-1
WHERE a.RN%2 > 0
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2f40/9/0)

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function adds a number to each row, it requires an `ORDER BY` clause, so if you want the ordering to not be arbitrary you will replace `(SELECT 1)` with a field from your table.

**Edit:**  I see that you want to randomize this, you can use `ORDER BY NEWID()` to get a random ordering, but when doing so you cannot count on the `cte` as it could result in team 1 being the same as team 2, instead you'll want to use a temp table:

```
SELECT FN + ' ' + LN AS Team
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RN
INTO #t
FROM Table1
;
SELECT a.Team AS Team1
      ,b.Team AS Team2
FROM #t a
JOIN #t b
  ON a.RN = b.RN-1
WHERE a.RN%2 > 0
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2f40/13/0)

Comment: See the edit near the bottom of the question, that will provide random pairings.

Comment: I got it Thanks Again 

WITH cte AS (SELECT firstname + ' ' + lastname AS Team1
                    , LEAD(firstname + ' ' + lastname,1) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Team2
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))RN
              FROM RegisteredUsers)
SELECT Team1, Team2
FROM cte
WHERE RN%2 > 0   order by NEWID()